# My iOS app displays multiple languages despite having only English selected in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

How do I fix this so only 'English' shows in the app store?

[This is what is set on iTunes Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnlcO.png)

[This is what my app looks like in the App Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j25u.png)

^It shows 5 languages when I only want it to show English.

[xcode also shows 5 languages see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSmhK.png)

^This image is from xcode, it shows 5 languages but I cannot edit them, is this why 5 languages are showing in the app store?

How can I fix this so only English gets displayed on the app store???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the extra localizations from Xcode shown in that screenshot.  When removing, make sure you have the Project selected and you should see the `-` icon displayed.   Not sure where you took that screenshot from but it doesn't look like the right place.

Comment: yeah I figured but it doesn't allow me to edit them that is the issue

Comment: Select the item under Project with your app name from the left frame of the middle section then the Info tab.   Localizations should show then.   Assuming you're on recent Xcode as well?

Comment: I think I got it but is this the reason why they were showing multiple languages in the app store?

Comment: Yep Apple reads the app size from the binary and pulls the localization info out of your app to figure out the languages.